# cx_freeze DLL load failed with Scipy

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

When using cx_freeze with my application I get the following error when runnig the executable:

[image]

The `setup.py` file is:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {
"includes": ['numpy', 'networkx', 'pandas', 'xlwt', 'matplotlib', 'xlsxwriter', 'numba', 'scipy.sparse.linalg', 'scipy.sparse.csgraph._validation'],
"packages": ['pkg_resources'],
'excludes' : [],
"include_files": [('C:\\Anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\scipy\\special\\_ufuncs.pyd','_ufuncs.pyd'), ('C:\\Anaconda3\Lib\\site-packages\\scipy\\sparse\\linalg\\isolve\\_iterative.pyd', '_iterative.pyd')]}


# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "GridCal",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "GridCal",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("main_gui.py", base=base)])
```

The `scipy.sparse.linalg.isolve._iterative.pyd` libary is there, so I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: The 'DLL load failed' error means it couldn't find another DLL needed by the file named in the error. You can use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to try to figure it out, but cx_Freeze has quite a few problems with Scipy.

Comment: Thanks, so as I understand, this means that there is another library that it's not being mentioned that is causing the problem?  When I use dependency walker the missing DLL's are: {API-MS-WIN-APPMODEL-RUNTIME-L1-1-0.DLL, API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ERROR-L1-1-0.DLL, API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-L1-1-0.DLL, API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-ROBUFFER-L1-1-0.DLL, API-MS-WIN-CORE-WINRT-STRING-L1-1-0.DLL, API-MS-WIN-SHCORE-SCALING-L1-1-1.DLL, DCOMP.DLL, IESHIMS.DLL }  What shall I do with this?